# SassError: unidentified variable $carbon--theme--g100;

Tags: indexing, styles, scss-mixins, carbon-components

Im following a tutorial for a portfolio react app, and I'm having trouble with the carbon theme compliling so I can run it.

I tried using different themes, such as g90 and g10, but it's still the same error. I also looked into my layout, and there isn't any typos that I can see so far. Here is my GitHub https://github.com/Maxdj2k/portfolio-create-react-app

the error occurs in src/index.scss